# How to produce 2 formats from the same stream and output to the same file in ffmpeg?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, conversion

I have an episode and I want to change it's audio from dts to eac3 and ac3 but i always get an error.
i used this command ffmpeg -i input -i input -c:v copy -c:m:0:1 eac3 -c:m:1:1 ac3 -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -map 1:1  output.mkv

Comment: You should post the output of the command. `-c:m` is something that I did not understand. Codecs are for audio or video (or even subtitles).

Answer (score 0):

As Rajib already points out, `-c:m` does not seem to be a valid parameter.

Should not be:

```
ffmpeg -i input -i input -c:v copy -c:a:0 eac3 -c:a:1 ac3 -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -map 1:1 output.mkv
```

See [Stream-specifiers](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-specifiers-1)